# GetColumnValue & EditValue not a member of system.windows.form.textbox

Tags: vb.net

[image]

This is my code. I want to display the PurokName instead of the PurokID.. But it says that `GetColumnValue/EditValue` is not a member of `System.Windows.Form.TextBox`.

this is my Purok Table :

[image]

Can anyone help me.

Comment: It seems like you have two different items here, one is a `TextBox`, one is a `Table`, but you treat the `TextBox` as if it is the `Table`

Comment: `GetColumnValue/EditValue` both related to Grid, you should use Grid Name instead of TextBox Name